# Apache: Setting up a reverse proxy configuration with SSL with url rewriting

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, https, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

There is a host: secure.foo.com that exposes a webservice using https

I want to create a reverse proxy using Apache that maps a local http port on a server internal.bar.com to the https service exposed by secure.foo.com

Since it a web service I need to map all urls so that a path:

https://secure.foo.com/some/path/123

is accessible by going to:

http://internal.bar.com/some/path/123

Thanks.

I've gotten this far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName gnip.measr.com
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPass / https://internal.bar.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I think this is working except for the url rewriting.

Some resources I've found on this are:

1. [Setting up a complex Apache reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/186225/setting-up-a-complex-apache-reverse-proxy)
2. [Apache as reverse proxy for https server](http://andriigrytsenko.net/2011/02/apache-as-reverse-proxy-for-https-server/)

Comment: Is the problem with URLs referenced in HTML/CSS/JS resources that aren't loading with the internal name?